# node_overview_types no hook? how to customize

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

Ok, i'm finally starting to understand how to use hooks! I am trying to customize the table that appears on `admin/structure/types`  I would like to add a custom link between `manage fields` and `manage display`.  I have tracked the creation of this down to the `node_overview_types` function in content_types.inc.  I did not see any hooks like hook_theme_table.  My initial response was to look for a hook_table_alter but I did not see one in the drupal api. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no specific theme function used the easiest way I can think of is to implement [`hook_page_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) and alter the table directly. The following code works for me:

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  if (request_path() == 'admin/structure/types') {
    // Get the types, they will automatically be in the same order as the rows
    // in the existing table
    $types = array_keys(node_type_get_types());
    $limit = count($types);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
      // Get the existing row
      $row = $page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#rows'][$i];

      // Get the type related to this row
      $type = $types[$i];

      // Make a link to add to the table
      $link = l('Link Text', 'my/path/to/' . $type);

      // Make up the new cell. I know there's an easier way to do this but
      // I can't for the life of me remember it right now
      $new_row = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $link, $row[3], $row[4]);

      // Overwrite the existing row with the new one
      $page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#rows'][$i] = $new_row;
    }

    // Increase the colspan of the header to take into account the new column
    $page['content']['system_main']['node_table']['#header'][1]['colspan'] = 5;
  }
}
```